# Cannot understand how to download secure files in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have uploaded file named `example.conf` in repository secure files and want to download that file while running CI / CD pipeline script. I tried following [Project-level Secure Files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secure_files/) in GitLab documentation, but still I do not understand what should be the correct path to the file.

My attempt was this:
`curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/download-secure-files/-/example.conf`

Which is apparently incorrect as I get the response:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I cannot access that file even if I do that through the browser, meanwhile URL provided in the documentation works. I don't understand from what URL should consist of as using `https://gitlab.com/<GROUP NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/download-secure-files/-/<FILE NAME>` does not work.

So, how do I access GitLab secure files form the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I didn't figure out how to how to do it using `download-secure-files` tool but GitLab provides API for working with secure files so I used that instead. My approach includes downloading data about secure files stored in the repository, extracting filename and id pairs and downloading each file.

1. Download data about secure files stored in this project:

```
curl --request GET -H "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/secure_files > secure_files.json
```

2. Extract file `id` and `name`.

```
cat secure_files.json | jq '.[] | "\(.id),\(.name)"' | tr -d '"' > files.txt
```

3. Download file contents.

```
while IFS=, read -a line;
do set -- "${line[@]}";
    curl --request GET --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/secure_files/$1/download > $2;
done < files.txt
```

Note: this only works in `bash` shell due to usage of, for example, `-a` flag in `read` command. I am not familiar enough with shell scripting to make this any more compatible or efficient.

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck at this for a while, too.

You don't need to change the url from the documentation.

Change the SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH to the path where you need your secret file to be, and curl the url. This will download all the files you uploaded as secret files to the stated path.

```
variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: './where/files/should/go/'
  script:
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
```

Comment: I am doing the exactly same thing, the CI logs states that the files were downloaded to 'my_path' but when I do a 'ls my_path' the files are not there. Have any idea why?